# Why does order by primary index make this query slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, sql-order-by, inner-join

This query is getting the newest videos uploaded by the user's subscriptions, its running very slow so I rewrote it to use joins but It didn't make a difference and after tinkering with it I found out that removing ORDER BY would make it run fast (however it defeats the purpose of the query).

Query:

```
SELECT vid. *
FROM video AS vid
INNER JOIN subscriptions AS sub ON vid.uploader = sub.subscription_id
WHERE sub.subscriber_id = '1'
AND vid.privacy = 0 AND vid.blocked <> 1 AND vid.converted = 1
ORDER BY vid.id DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Running explain, it would show "Using temporary; Using filesort" in subscriptions table and its slow (0.0900 seconds).

Without ORDER BY vid.id DESC it doesn't show "Using temporary; Using filesort" so its fast (0.0004 seconds) but I don't understand how the other table can affect it like this.

All the fields are indexed (privacy blocked and converted fields don't affect performance by more than 10%).

I would paste the full explain information but I can't seem to make it fit nice in the layout of this site.

Comment: you SHOULD include index, and execution plan, try use the `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by suggesting that mysql use the primary index with USE_INDEX(PRIMARY)

```
SELECT vid. *
FROM video AS vid USE INDEX ( PRIMARY )
INNER JOIN subscriptions AS sub ON vid.uploader = sub.subscription_id
WHERE sub.subscriber_id = '1'
AND vid.privacy =0
AND vid.blocked <>1
AND vid.converted =1
ORDER BY vid.id DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: This is interesting. Any idea what it was doing before? Using a different index?

Answer (score 3):

You're limiting the query to 8 results. When you run it without an `order by`, it can grab the first 8 rows it comes across that pass the condition, and then hand them back. Boom, it's done.

When you use the `order by`, you're not asking for **any** 8 records. You're asking for the **first** 8 records in terms of `vid.id`. So it has to figure out which those are, and the only way to do that is to look through the entire table and compare `vid.id` values. That's a lot more work.

Is there actually an index on the column? If so, it may be out of date. You could try rebuilding it.

Comment: There is an index and its a primary index, tried repairing and optimizing it and It didn't change the speed.
Also using that table by itself, ordering by id is very fast.